# Using media queries for mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

When viewing my site on a mobile device, the content is aligned center (the way it is on desktop view) but at the expense of the content area being even smaller than it already would be on a mobile device. If you look at my site through this mobile tester, you'll see exactly what I mean. I've been playing around with css queries, but since I'm a beginner with that, I haven't had much luck.

Can anyone help me get my content to fill out the screen on smaller devices rather than end up as one long, narrow area?

here is my site: http://mobiletest.me/iphone_5_emulator/#u=http://monpetitfour.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have applied 100px padding for left and right of your body content. When it comes to mobile device, you should reduces or remove it using media queries.

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    body 
    {
      padding:0px 10px;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I completely forgot about the padding!

Answer (score 0):

Add this css on page It will work for all mobile devices

```
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {

body {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    padding: 0;
}
#page {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0 1.11111rem;
}

img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
.site-main {
    width: 100%;
}
.simple-social-icons ul li a, .simple-social-icons ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #fff !important;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #ccc !important;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 8px;
}

}
```